# Can't get email folder names using IMAPX

Tags: wpf, vb.net, email, imapx

I am using this code to get the list of email folders :

```
Class emailFolder
    Public Property Title As String
End Class

Public Shared Function GetFolders() As List(Of emailFolder)
    Dim folder = New List(Of emailFolder)
    Dim foldername = client.Folders
    For Each parentFolder In foldername
        Dim parentPath = parentFolder.Path
        If parentFolder.HasChildren Then
            Dim subfolders = parentFolder.SubFolders
            For Each subfolder In subfolders
                Dim subPath = subfolder.Path
                folder.Add(New emailFolder With {.Title = parentFolder.Name})
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return folder
End Function

Public sub btn_click handles Button1.click

ListView.ItemSource=GetFolders
```

I dunno what is wrong with my code but the items I get in the `ListView` (I'm in wpf by the way) look like this :

```
 MyApplication++emailfolder
 MyApplication++emailfolder
 MyApplication++emailfolder
 MyApplication++emailfolder
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This is all dependent on what `client.Folders` actually contains.

Comment: @AFriend,i don't understand....i am retrieving email from my gmail account.....all the examples online uses this same code but they can retrieve the folders ..i can't...any help ?

Comment: Have you tried providing a `ToString` override for your class so that the listview knows what information to display? Without it, it will just give the type, same as if you try and `ToString` a list.

Comment: i moved the code out of the class and added it in a button's click event(i also added the code to connect/log in to email server/account )..i used `parentfolder.tostring`...but same result bro

Comment: okey...i tried `listview.itemsource=getfolders.tostring` now the result is wayyy moreeee weird !! the items are as follows : `s` `y` `s` `t` `e` `m` `.` g` i mean each item is just a letter....but it's weird that if i combine the letters,the word that i get is `system.generic.blablabla...`

Comment: You need to set the [`DataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the ListView.

Comment: i don't understand properly,can u show me a sample code?

Comment: i found [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) but really don't understand how to implement it in my case

Comment: zack, the link you just shared have a very simple example of how to override `ToString()`, like @AFriend suggested. You have the solution right in front of you. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent,i'lll try to fix it :)

Comment: damn!!!!!! Fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved..Thanks for the comments guys!!

Just had to override  the `ToString`....Full code:

```
   Class emailFolder
    Public Property Title As String
   Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Me.Title
        End Function
End Class

  Public Shared Function GetFolders() As List(Of emailFolder)
    Dim folder = New List(Of emailFolder)
    Dim foldername = client.Folders
    For Each parentFolder In foldername
        Dim parentPath = parentFolder.Path
        If parentFolder.HasChildren Then
            Dim subfolders = parentFolder.SubFolders
            For Each subfolder In subfolders
                Dim subPath = subfolder.Path
                folder.Add(New emailFolder With {.Title = parentFolder.Name})
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return folder
End Function

Public sub btn_click handles Button1.click

ListView.ItemSource=GetFolders
```

Comment: This is an override of the `ToString()`-method. NOT the same as `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Though you ought to edit your answer and correct your statement. Like Mat says you are _**overriding `ToString()`**_. You are _NOT_ using the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the [`ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `ListView`, you can define how the ListViewItems should look like.

With the following example just the content of the property `Title` will be displayed:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

---

Another approach is to add an override of the `ToString`-method to the `emailFolder`-class:

```
Class emailFolder
    Public Property Title As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Title
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But the first method is an alternative to the `ToString()`-override you used and thus worth to mention.